# How to delete every 5 rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I want to delete particular rows, and leave the ones that have the first occurrence  of the machine ID.
So I want row 0, 5, 10 and 15

```
0,M_0003
1,M_0003
2,M_0003
3,M_0003
4,M_0003
5,M_0005
6,M_0005
7,M_0005
8,M_0005
9,M_0005
10,M_0007
11,M_0007
12,M_0007
13,M_0007
14,M_0007
15,M_0003
16,M_0003
17,M_0003
18,M_0003
19,M_0003
```

That's how the result should look like:

```
0,M_0003
1,M_0005
2,M_0007
3,M_0003
```

Is there a function in Python that will help?
The only thing I found is this, but it does not work.

```
y_data = y_data.groupby(np.arange(len(y_data)) // 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
y_data = y_data.groupby(np.arange(len(y_data)) // 5).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
y_data = y_data[np.arange(len(y_data))%5==0]
```

intermediates:

```
np.arange(len(y_data))%5
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

np.arange(len(y_data))%5==0
# array([ True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
#        False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
#        False, False])
```